# Unity3d DllNotFoundException is showing a directory that doesn't exist on my computer

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, dll, plugins

I'm trying to use an asset in my unity project, it has a c# script.cs that calls and initializes the plugins, when the game starts.
but when I press the play button, unity keeps throwing DllNotFoundException

[image: image of exception]

this is the picture of the error i get when i play the game
(sorry, i had to send a picture and censor some parts, because of the term of use i signed)

the error says

> at "C:/Users/thatcompany/source/repos/plugin-name/plugin-name-api/a-class-in-plugin.cs:192"

and this path doesn't even exist on my computer

this asset is for unity3d and is written in c# and c++.
the code that is used for initialization is written in c#, it uses a DLL file which is also written in c#, and that DLL file uses another DLL file which is written in c++ and has

```c#
[DllImport("DllThatUnityCantFind", EntryPoint = "name_initialize", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern IntPtr Name_initialize(int argc, string[] argv);
```

this is the only line of code that I found useful for this question, as the other lines don't even get a chance to get executed.

I've have read all of the related questions on this website and others and tried these answers,

- putting DLL files in the root of the project
- putting DLL files in unity editor main folder
- separating DLL files into different directories
- putting dependant DLL files into the root of the project while having the other one in the plugin folder and visa versa
- switching Scripting Runtime Version to 3.5 and 4.x
- changing API capability Level
- making a new project
- restarting the editor
- opening the unity editor as administrator
- updating unity to the version that this plugin is tested on
- updating unity to the latest version
- changing name of the DLL file to name.dll.dll instead of name.dll
- changing the platform setting of the plugin
- installing all the different versions of VC redist 2005-2019, 32 and 64 bits
- updating to the latest version of .net core and .net framework

[image: DLL Import Settings]

The DLL file that unity can't import also shows a warning message

[image: dependency walker]

the DLL file that can't be found in unity, in dependency walker

Comment: The _doesn't even exist on my computer_ is the path to the source file on the _developer's_ (vendor's) computer, not yours.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, is it something wrong? can it be the source of the problem?

Comment: That's where it is trying to load the DLL that it can't find.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm do you have any solution?

Comment: have you tried first contacting the plugin developer?

Comment: @DavidYenglin yes, they said the plugin works perfectly, and they also tried the plugin on a fresh computer and sent me a video that showed it was working fine.

Comment: [Here's a list](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-fix-dll-errors-2624492) of common things to try when a missing DLL occurs. Just make sure you're not grabbing the DLL off a third party website as a attempt at a fix, don't know where those DLL's have been and they are not to be trusted.

Comment: @TimHunter thanks for the comment, I'll try all the 12 steps to see what happens, I wish one of them fixes my problem.

Comment: @AmirrezaYegane Any luck with those potential fixes?

Comment: @TimHunter no, i tried all the 12 steps include reinstalling windows, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That DLL links against VS 2015 debug runtime (MSVCP140D.dll). Unless Visual Studio 2015 with C++ workload is installed on your machine, the DLL will not load.

This is a bug in the .DLL - DLLs that get distributed should not be compiled against debug C++ runtime. I suggest contacting the person you got this DLL from and ask them to rebuild it in "Release" config. While you're at it, you might also want to ask them to link CRT statically, as otherwise you'll have to have VS 2015 C++ redistributable package installed on the machine you're trying to use that DLL on.

Comment: OMG, you're not the hero i deserved, but the hero i needed ♥♥
i grabbed visual studio 2015 installer from the internet
@ 2% i saw it's installing vc 2015 debug run time, i opened unity and that was it.
now it's working